# show element not working

Tags: javascript, html

Hi I have a problem with my function, when I call it to show my hidden div it does not work. It does not show the hidden div. I followed previous examples from what have been posted in stackoverflow but still my code does not work.

This is my html file

```
<div id="playTheGame" class="css/outer" style="display:none;" >
    <div class="css/inner">      
        <h1>Choose!</h1>
                    <section id="hand">
                <img src="images/rock.png">
                <img src="images/paper.png">
                <img src="images/scissors.png">
            </section>
 </div>
 </div>
```

My Function

```
<script>
function logSuccess(){
    document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.visibility="visible";
}
</script>
```

The Button I used for the function

```
<input type="button" onclick="logSuccess()" value="Show">
```

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/q/133051/1618713 this question has many good answers for visibility hidden vs display none confusion.

Answer (score 1):

Change your code to this

```
document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.display = "block";
```

Since you hid it using the display property, show it using the display property.

Comment: Thank you so much. This worked out well for me. I was referring to this website at first. http://www.w3schools.com/jsref/prop_style_visibility.asp and thus I got the code visibility="visible"

Comment: I guess, Jeffman is right, since you used display to hide it, you need to use display to get it back too!

Comment: For your information http://stackoverflow.com/questions/133051/what-is-the-difference-between-visibilityhidden-and-displaynone

Comment: Sorry for the very noob question. Just started learning javascript. Thanks guys! This helped me a lot.

Comment: One last question so if I want to hide it should I use document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.visibility="hidden";  ? or there is another way for this?

Comment: That will work, but you want to be consistent, or the page will jump around. `document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.display = "none";`

Answer (score 0):

There are two options for this:

One using JavaScript:

```
object.style.display="block"; // where object will be the playThemGame id element..
```

And the other one using jQuery; JavaScript library.

```
$("#playTheGame").show();
```

The option two won't work, because you will have to write the event function too, So just use the first one as:

```
document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.display="block";
```

**Edit:**

Since you are using

```
document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.display="block";
```

To disply the result, then you must use this to remove the display!

```
document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.display = "none"; to hide it back!
```

The basic idea is that, this will just shift the `object-->style-->display`'s value to `none` Its not going to add any more attribute. Its just going to shift current attribute's value.

Comment: One last question so if I want to hide it should I use document.getElementById("playTheGame").style.visibility="hidden";  ? or there is another way for this?